# What does this string in the Manifest mean?

Tags: android, xml, encoding, utf-8, android-manifest

What exactly does **"0x000004B4"** mean? I have seen **android:configChanges=** before when regarding screen orientation, or pixel density, but have no idea what these letters and numbers mean. I'm very new and would like to know how the more commonly seen strings work. Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be great if you could show the content you are asking about as part of the question, even if you just share part of the AndroidManifest.xml instead of the whole thing it would be a great help! What you are seeing though is most likely a hexadecimal representation of the specified value instead of the name or an integer representation.

Comment: It'x a hex code for the int 1204. What it does depends on the context

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that each attribute in the "android:configChanges" field resolves to a different value:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges

So my guess is that the attribute values somehow add up to uniquely identify which attributes were added in the Manifest.